# Start Service Ahead of Persistence Unit Service in JBoss Weld

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0

I currently have an application that uses JBoss to start services and manage EJB using weld. When it goes to start our Persistence Unit Manager which uses custom classes, the @EJB annotations as well as the services are null and have not been called. Is there a way to set an order to force a service to start ahead of the persistence unit?

Comment: Do you have some code to illustrate your issue?

Comment: Not particularly. It's pretty complex to demonstrate here and involves more configuration. Services have standard @ startup and @ singleton. All other magic is handled by jboss which I dont have code for. Using standard persistance.xml for hibernate and postgres.

Comment: So first question what is Persistence Unit Manager?

Comment: Persistence Unit Manager service is the internal jboss/spring component service that builds your connections based on prescribed configuration. In this case, using persistence.xml

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend configuring JTA Datasource in JBoss Application Server so that you can monitor pooled connection objects and their usage.

Copy this inside Datasource Subsystem in `standalone.xml`:
**Note: You need to register jdbc drivers of vendor database server before using this datasource.**

[Adding Database Driver in JBoss and Wildfly.](http://giordanomaestro.blogspot.in/2015/02/install-jdbc-driver-on-wildfly.html)

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/datasource/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME" pool-name="YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME" enabled="true" use-ccm="true" statistics-enabled="true"><!--JNDI Name which will be used in your persistence.xml in your applicaton-->
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://server-ip-here:3306/your-database-name</connection-url><!-- change according to your database-->
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class><!-- change according to your database-->
                    <connection-property name="zeroDateTimeBehavior">
                        convertToNull
                    </connection-property>
                    <driver>mysql</driver><!-- change according to your database-->
                    <new-connection-sql>SELECT 1</new-connection-sql>
                    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>3</min-pool-size>
                        <initial-pool-size>3</initial-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                        <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>db-user-name</user-name>
                        <password>db-user-password</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/><!-- change according to your database-->
                        <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
                        <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/><!-- change according to your database-->
                    </validation>
                    <timeout>
                        <blocking-timeout-millis>6000</blocking-timeout-millis>
                        <idle-timeout-minutes>30</idle-timeout-minutes>
                        <query-timeout>60</query-timeout>
                        <allocation-retry>4</allocation-retry>
                        <allocation-retry-wait-millis>200</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
                    </timeout>
                    <statement>
                        <track-statements>true</track-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
```

Your `src/main/java/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml` file should look like this:

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="myAppPu" transaction-type="JTA">
        <description>Persistence Unit for MyApp Database</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc:mysql://server-ip-here:3306/your-database-name</jta-data-source><!--This is already defined in newly created datasource-->

        !--<validation-mode>CALLBACK</validation-mode>-->
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-database-schemas" value="false" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="none" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"></property>
            <property name="use_sql_comments" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"></property>
            <!-- Hibernate Envers -->
            <!--<property name="hibernate.auditable" value="false" />-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Now you are ready to use EntityManager in your application.
Example usage:

```
@Stateless
public class MyEjbServiceImpl implements MyEjbService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myAppPu") //this should match with unitname defined in persistence.xml
    private EntityManager em;

}
```